# Using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer, how can I compute memory usage per webapp?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer ([1](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)), I can see in general what classes are consuming memory, but I would like to know which webapp is responsible for how much memory.  If I just search the dominator tree for instances of the class loader used by Tomcat to load each webapp, this does not reveal the count I am looking for.  I assume this is because the web apps have many threads, including Tomcat HTTP processor threads, that are keeping objects alive.  Also, I guess that objects reference their class loader, but not the other way around.

How can I compute the total size of all objects loaded into a specific class loader using mat? Is this possible?